# what is the value of arguments in command hadoop fs <args>

Tags: hadoop3

hadoop 3.3.1
I am learning Hadoop,and find a command

```
hadoop fs -ls <args>
```

What is the possible value of <args>?

Answer (score 0):

OK,I know why.
by default,only '/' directory exists.